# Translate model fields' attributes from a Database with Django?

Tags: django, translation

I'm trying to create a Model that has fields that have the following attributes translatable: verbose_name and choices. I can easily do this by tagging the strings and using the i18l middleware. The problem is that I don't want to define the translation in po/mo files. Is there a way to pull this data from a database table? If so, any examples?

There are some options out there that offer model content translation. That is not my case. I need to translate the verbose_name, choices and error_messages from database.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of translation apps out there. I found [this blog entry](http://www.muhuk.com/2010/01/dynamic-translation-apps-for-django/) which reviews a few of them.

Comment: I'm not sure if any of them translate the choices attribute. It seems all they do is the verbose_name attribute.